# Reading a file with Strings and floats and assigning them to arrays

Tags: java, arrays

I want to design a code that can read a file that looks like this:

Jake 12.00 13.24 6

Sarah 11.23 24.01 8

Alex 10.65 19.45 4

I need to make separate arrays for the Strings, the first float, the second float, and the int. 
How do I go about doing this?

This is what I have so far: I'm not sure how to make separate arrays for the two floats. I also keep getting an `exception IndexOutOfBoundsException: 0 at EmployeePay.main..`

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.*;
 public class EmployeePay {
   public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException  {
    if (args.length != 1) {  
        final String msg = "Usage: EmployeePay name_of_input file";
          System.err.println(msg);
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(msg);
           }

      final String inputFileName = args[0];
      final File input = new File (inputFileName); 
      final Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new BufferedReader(new FileReader(input)));
              String Id = "Employee Id:";
              String Hours = "Hours worked:";
              String WageRate = "Wage Rate:";
              String Deductions = "Deductions:";
              System.out.printf("%s %-10s %-20s %-30s", Id, Hours, WageRate, Deductions);

              int lineNumber = 0;
           while (scanner.hasNextLine()){
            lineNumber =lineNumber +1;
            String [] Identification= new String [lineNumber-1];
            int [] TotalDeductions = new int [lineNumber-1];
            float [] WorkTime = new float[lineNumber-1];    
                if(scanner.hasNextInt()){
                    TotalDeductions[lineNumber-1] = scanner.nextInt();
                    System.out.println(TotalDeductions[lineNumber-1]);

            }
              else if (scanner.hasNextFloat()){
                WorkTime[lineNumber-1]= scanner.nextFloat();


              }
               else {
                Identification[lineNumber-1] = scanner.next();
                System.out.println(Identification[lineNumber-1]);
               }


           }

       }
   }
```

Comment: 1. First, you learn the Java programming language to the point that you understand enough of the concepts to implement this. 2. Once you're there, you try to implement it 3. When you have code that attempts to do what you want, but you have problems that you don't understand and are stuck, then you can post a question here, that includes a [mcve] and a good description of what and where the problem is.

Comment: I've been working through this for the past 3 hours. I've tried implementing it, but haven't been able to successfully figure out how to make different arrays for the two floats. I can post the code I have as a separate question

Comment: @NatanSiegel All the lines will have same pattern (`Jake 12.00 13.24 6`) ? And the `String` portion won't have any space?

Comment: @ShubhenduPramanik Yes to both questions

Answer (score 0):

I will assume your String value doesn't contain space. This is kind of pseudo code, Try yourself and explore each line why I did so:

```
String s[] = new String[size];
float f1[] = new float[size];
float f2[] = new float[size];
for(int i=0; i<numberOfLines;i++) {
    String x = "Jake 12.00 13.24 6";

    String[] arr = x.split(" ");
    s[i] = arr[0];
    f1[i] = Float.valueOf(arr[1]);
    f2[i] = Float.valueOf(arr[2]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This error `exception IndexOutOfBoundsException: 0 at EmployeePay.main.` is occuring due to this statement `if (args.length != 1)`.
It should be `if(args.length!=0)`
If no arguements are passed at command prompt then `args.length` is 0. So, this statement will throw an exception `final String inputFileName = args[0];`
Thus, you need to check for `args.length`

Answer (score 0):

If your data file is indeed as you show in your post with blank lines between the data lines then you will need to take care of those as well while reading the file and processing the information obtained. You obviously want to skip past those particular lines. If this isn't the case then it only goes to show you how important it is to provide full and accurate information when asking a question here. No one here wants to really assume anything.

When creating arrays it's always nice to know how big an array needs to be beforehand so that you can properly initialize it to its required size. This is where List or ArrayList is better, you can just add to them when needed. Never the less, to properly initialize all your different arrays (String[], float[], float[], and int[]) you need to know how many valid data line are contained within your data file. By valid data lines I mean lines that actually contain data, not blank lines. So the first natural step would be to count those lines. Once you have the count then you can initialize all your arrays to that line count.

Now all you need to do is re-read the file data line by line, split each line to acquire the data segments , then convert each numerical segment to its respective Array data type. Once you have all your arrays filled from the file you can then do whatever you like with the data contained within those arrays. The code to carry out this task might look something like this:

```
String inputFileName = "MyDataFile.txt";
Scanner scanner;
int linesCount = 0;
try {
    // Count the total number of valid data lines
    // within the file (blank line are skipped).
    scanner = new Scanner(new File(inputFileName));
    while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
        String strg = scanner.nextLine().trim();
        if (!strg.equals("")) { linesCount++; }
    }

    // Declare our different Arrays and size them to
    // the valid number of data lines in file.
    String[] employeeID = new String[linesCount];
    float[] hours = new float[linesCount];
    float[] wageRate = new float[linesCount];
    int[] deductions = new int[linesCount];

    // Read through the file again and place the data 
    // into their respective arrays.
    scanner = new Scanner(new File(inputFileName));
    int counter = 0;
    while (scanner.hasNextLine()){
        // Get the next line in file...
        String strg = scanner.nextLine().trim();
        // If the file line is blank then skip it.
        if (strg.equals("")) { continue; }
        // otherwise split the line by its space
        // delimiter ("\\s+" takes care of 1 OR more
        // spaces just in case).
        String[] values = strg.split("\\s+");
        // Add to the employeeID string array.
        employeeID[counter] = values[0];
        // Control what is placed into the elements of each 
        // float or integer array. If there is no value data 
        // supplied in file for the employee Name then make 
        // sure 0.0 (for floats) or 0 (for integers) is placed 
        // there after all, you can't parse a null string ("").
        if (values.length >= 2) { hours[counter] = Float.parseFloat(values[1]); }
        else { hours[counter] = 0.0f; }
        if (values.length >= 3) { wageRate[counter] = Float.parseFloat(values[2]); }
        else { wageRate[counter] = 0.0f; }               
        if (values.length == 4) { deductions[counter] = Integer.parseInt(values[3]); }
        else { deductions[counter] = 0; }
        counter++;
    }
    scanner.close();

    // Now that you have all your arrays you can
    // do whatever you like with the data contained
    // within them:
    String Id = "Employee Id:";
    String Hours = "Hours worked:";
    String WageRate = "Wage Rate:";
    String Deductions = "Deductions:";
    System.out.printf("%-15s %-15s %-15s %-15s%n", Id, Hours, WageRate, Deductions);
    for (int i = 0; i < employeeID.length; i++) {
        System.out.printf("%-15s %-15s %-15s %-15s%n", employeeID[i], hours[i], wageRate[i], deductions[i]);
    }
} 
catch (FileNotFoundException ex) { ex.printStackTrace(); }
```